# Discord.py intents error, how do I fix this?

Tags: discord.py

I am getting an Attribute Error containing the following:

````
  File "bot.py", line 30, in <module>
    intents = discord.intents.default()
AttributeError: module 'discord' has no attribute 'intents' ```
````

Comment: Intents should start capitalized, python is a case-sensitive language.

Answer (score 0):

`intents` should start with a capitalised `I`(That means `discord.Intents.default()`

Sources:

- in comments of your post — by Łukasz Kwieciński
- [#discord.Intents in discord.ext.commands api reference](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Intents), as it said `class discord.Intents(**kwargs)`